# Alingning object to motion tracked scene

Tags: camera, tracking

I have a scene which I have motion tracked. I'm having trouble adding objects to the scene though. I cant seem to get a cube to line up with the base of the sign. I have the correct size of sensor and focal length of phone camera according to google but it doesn't seem to match up at all. The phone has a wide angle lens which i think distorts everything. Is there any way to deal with this so that I can get blender's camera to match the footage?

[image]

trying to add cube.

[image]

Comment: Read: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)